# Why my image buttons are not appearing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to place two image buttons on my image background in a certain position, but my buttons are not appearing. I think their images are behind the background.

I tried to use `place` and `pack`, both did not work. What could be the problem?

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
import settings

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__ (self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        button1 = PhotoImage(file ="button1.gif")
        button2 = PhotoImage(file ="button2.gif")
        settings_button = Button(self, image = button1, 
                                 command = self.mult_command, width = 15)
        settings_button.place(x=1, y=1)
        rules_button = Button(self, image = button2, 
                              command = self.the_rules, width = 15)
        rules_button.place(x=50, y=50)

def main_code():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("The Bouncer")
    bg_image = PhotoImage(file ="pic.gif")
    x = Label (image = bg_image)
    x.image = bg_image
    x.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    window.geometry("600x300")
    app = Application(window)
    window.mainloop()

main_code()
```

thanks

Answer (score 5):

It is likely that your image is being garbage collected before it is displayed. This is a common Tkinter gotcha. Try changing the lines:

```
button1 = PhotoImage(file ="button1.gif")
button2 = PhotoImage(file ="button2.gif")
```

to

```
self.button1 = PhotoImage(file ="button1.gif")
self.button2 = PhotoImage(file ="button2.gif")
```

and use

```
settings_button = Button(self, image = self.button1, command = self.mult_command, width = 15)
```

etc.

This should keep a reference to your image, stopping it from getting garbage collected.

Comment: yes that did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

In addition to keeping a reference to the image, you have a problem with this line:

```
self.grid()
```

in the `__init__` method of `Application`. It's gridding the Frame into the window, but since nothing is ever packed or gridded into the frame, it doesn't ever expand past a little, tiny frame, so you just don't see the Buttons inside it. A simple fix here would be the `pack` method, with arguments to `fill` the window and `expand` when needed:

```
self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

Comment: Ok. I changed grid() to pad(), and it seems to be better now. I can see my background image and my buttons, but not the buttons on top of the BG image. Do you kknow how I can fix this?

Comment: Move the label with the bg image into the Frame. After you pack the frame, place the bg image, then create the widgets.

Comment: Sorry I still didnt get it.

Comment: You're not assigning the Label that contains the image to a parent. If you create the Label within the constructor of the Application class, you can put it in the same Frame as the buttons, and draw it under the buttons.